# Return type deduction in C++14 in assignment

Tags: c++, c++14, return-type

I was wondering whether a return type deduction in an assignment is possible in C++14 in some way. It feels redundant to type the `<int>` after the `return_five` function name. Thus, in other words, can the compiler use information from the left hand side of the assignment?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
auto return_five()
{
    return static_cast<T>(5);
}

int main()
{
    int five_int = return_five();         // THIS DOES NOT WORK
    // int five_int = return_five<int>(); // THIS WORKS

    std::cout << "Five_int = " << five_int << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Obviously, compiler needs to know what `T` is.

Comment: But it could assume that since I assign to an `int`, that the desired return type is an `int`?

Comment: Will end with `auto auto = auto();`

Comment: `auto five_int = return_five<int>();` removes the redundance as well, but is valid

Comment: Not such a bad question IHMO especially given that some langagues (VBA) infer the type of the RHS of an assignment from the type of the LHS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ ain't VBA: the thing on the left hand side of the assignment is **not** used to deduce the *type* of the right hand side.

So the compiler requires an explicit type for `return_five()`. You inform the compiler of the type by writing `return_five<int>()`.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, but this is the best you can do:

```
int main() {
  auto five_int = return_five<int>();
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not so much return type deduction as it is templating the return type:

```
template<typename T>
T return_five()
{
    return 5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Template parameters of functions are only deduced from function arguments, not from return types (unfortunately).

Possibly not of much interest to you, but a way to deduce the template parameters is the following:

```
template<typename T>
void return_five(T& value)
{
    value = static_cast<T>(5);
}

...

int five_int;
return_five(five_int);
```

Comment: I've seen this pattern of using unused 'tag' arguments as sources of types instead of template arguments, but never in a form that seemed useful. Even the better form, which doesn't pollute the scope with a pointless name - `return_five( int{} ) ` - is more verbose and less intuitive than good old `return_five<int>()`. Obviously it might be useful in a case where templates somehow can't be used or at least are undesirable, but I didn't see any example yet (not that I searched exhaustively).

Answer (score 0):

Well, this works :

```
struct return_five {
    template <class T>
    operator T() const { return 5; }
};

int main (int, char**) {
    int five_int = return_five();

    std::cout << five_int << '\n';
}
```

Hint : you *probably* don't want to actually use that in production code.